# ParameterizedTest in Junit5

Tags: selenium, junit5, parameterized

I've been looking at examples of parameterizing tests in junit 5 (which I am new to), but have not found what I'm looking for (unless I'm misunderstanding how to use them).

Basically I want to write a single (selenium/UI based) test and make it run multiple times. The paramaters I want to base the multiple runs on are custom objects that I have in my codebase.

An example I'm trying to implement would be - my test creates an appointment on a calendar with a customer, then does some assertions as to whether the appointment shows correctly and has expected details. A second test run would do the same but WITHOUT a customer. The assertions between the two test runs might slightly differ but largely the same code is run both times.

All the examples I seem to come across use primitive types like strings, or csv files, or methodSource, but none of these seem to fit what I'm trying to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is your question related to the possibility to include custom (not just primitive) types to '@Parametrized annotation?

Comment: it would be nice if you post your original code(if it's possible for ou to do so)

Comment: @gokareless - my question is around both possibility AND how one would actually go about it. To be precise it's not the '@Parameterized' annotation but the '@ParameterizedTest' annotation used in junit5 in particular. I might be able to post some code when I'm back at work on Monday, but I'm not sure it's super useful in this case?

Comment: With `@MethodSource` you can return `Arguments` instances that contain any kind of objects you want. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Not really @SamBrannen can you show an example?

Comment: Sure. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

With `@MethodSource` you can return `Arguments` instances that contain literally any kind of objects you want. There are no limitations regarding primitives, etc.

For a concrete example, check out the `testWithMultiArgMethodSource()` example in the [@MethodSource](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources-MethodSource) section of the JUnit 5 User Guide.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working example to showcase some variations of using  @ParameterizedTest

Example with inline parameters in the @ValueSource

```
@DisplayName("compare the name case insensetive")
  @ValueSource(strings = {"sanjAY", "SanjAY", "SANJay", "sanJAy"})
  @ParameterizedTest
  void compareTest(String sampleName) {
    assertThat(sampleName.toUpperCase().equals("SANJAY"));
  }
```

Additionally we can annotate with `@NullAndEmptySource` which will test your code against `null` and `empty` strings

Example when parameters are complex.

```
@DisplayName("compare the name case insensetive")
  @MethodSource("com.example.TestSamples#sampleNames")
  @ParameterizedTest
  void compareTest(List<String> names) {
    names.stream().forEach(x-> assertThat(x.endsWith("a")));
  }
```

Create a class TestSamples in com.example package and put below method

```
 public static List<String> sampleNames() {
    return List.of("Ganga","Yamuna","Radha","Java","Lava");
  }
```